# Multiple Submit in a Drupal Form

Tags: 7, forms

I want a list of the input of my saved database table with buttons to delete or view the content and want to redirect it in the submit function.

With this code snipped i get only the submitted input value of the buttons, but every time is the `$form_state['values']` array filled with the 1st form values. Is that the right way or need I another solution?

```
function myform_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    global $user;
    $uid = $user->uid;
    $utime = $user->timezone;

    $query = db_select('mytable', 'm');
    $query->condition('m.uid', $uid, '=');
    $query->fields('m', array('fid', 'uid', 'name', 'created'));
    $query->range(0, 50);

    $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    if($uid) {  
        switch ($delta) {
            case 'myblock':
                $block['subject'] = '<none>';
                $block['content'] = _block_content($results);
            break;
        };
    };  
    return $block;
}

function _block_content($items) {
    $output = array();

    foreach($items as $item => $item_value) {
        $output[$item] = drupal_get_form('mymodule_form', $item_value);
    };
    return $output;
}

function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state, $i) {

    global $user;
    $uid = $user->uid;
    $utime = $user->timezone;

        $form['value-'.$i->fid] = array( //EDIT
            '#type' => 'value',
            '#value' => $i->fid,
        );
        $form['view-'.$i->fid] = array ( //EDIT
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('view'),
            '#name' => 'view-'.$i->fid,
        );
        $form['delete-'.$i->fid] = array ( //EDIT
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('delete'),
            '#name' => 'delete-'.$i->fid,
        );

    return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   dpm($form_state);
   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; //EDIT
}
```

The dpm output without 'form_build_id' 'form_token' 'form_id' in both,
1st example:

```
input =>  
    view-3 => view
    value3 (NULL)

values =>     
    value2
    view-2 => view
    delete-2 => delete
```

2nd example:

```
input =>  
    view-3 => view
    value3 (NULL)

values =>     
    value3
    view-3 => view
    delete-3 => delete
```

Comment: can you add the result of the dpm?

Comment: I write one of the dpm after the changes of Yogesh. This is the one wich matched with the submit input.

Comment: This dpm makes no sense... can you check that it's most recent after your updates to the code?

Comment: That`s what i get. I add a 2nd dpm output in my question from one submit.

Comment: Can you add a dpm of $i in mymodule_form?

Comment: The $i gives the query from the database and this also for every loop, that is all fine. Only the submit makes me little bit crazy.

Answer (score 1):

It should be because the way you're generating the form is wrong, form element should be as below:

```
<?php
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state, $i) {
  $form['value_' . $i->fid] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $i->fid,
  );
  $form['view_' . $i->fid] = array (
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('view'),
    '#name' => 'view_' . $i->fid,
  );
  $form['delete_' . $i->fid] = array (
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('delete'),
    '#name' => 'delete_' . $i->fid,
  );

  return $form;
}
?>
```

Each element name in `$form` array should be unique. Check [Drupal Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/) guide for more details. The `value`, `view` and `delete` doesn't contain any form element data like `#type`, etc. Please check the value of `$form_state['values']['op']` in your form submit handler to understand which one is called.

Comment: Ah, you have right! Now I can compare the 'input' with the 'values' in the $form_state array. I forgot the $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; in the submit function too. The submit is calling for every loop. I havn`t any 'op' in 'values', also the value doesn`t help, it returns only the value of the current loop in 'input'. Is there not a better solution?

Comment: In submit handler you can check for `$form_state['values']['op']` which will give you which submit button is clicked, suppose for e.g. `delete_2` so you'll have that to identify.

Comment: Really I havn`t any 'op' in $form_state['values'], the values changes all with the fid in the loop. Only the 'input' displays me the clicked button. I can write two of the dpm outputs if you want.